# Installing python-blosc on arch

Tags: python, archlinux

[It appears](https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc/blob/ed6ba6073faf2b72431168e334bb5a86a2703e3a/c-blosc/RELEASE_NOTES.rst#changes-from-136-to-140) that python-blosc is supposed to work on the pi, but on my rpi2 running arch, after cloning the git repo and running `python setup.py install`, I'm getting the output below. Anyone else have any luck?

```
[user@scene_pi python-blosc]$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to blosc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to blosc.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing blosc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
reading manifest file 'blosc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
warning: no files found matching '*.cpp' under directory 'c-blosc'
warning: no files found matching '*.hpp' under directory 'c-blosc'
writing manifest file 'blosc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4
creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc
copying blosc/test.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc
copying blosc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc
copying blosc/version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc
copying blosc/toplevel.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc
running build_ext
building 'blosc.blosc_extension' extension
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc/blosc
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc/internal-complibs
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-1.7.0
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fPIC -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-1.7.0 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c blosc/blosc_extension.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc/blosc_extension.o
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fPIC -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-1.7.0 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c c-blosc/blosc/blosc.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc/blosc/blosc.o
c-blosc/blosc/blosc.c: In function 'blosc_getitem':
c-blosc/blosc/blosc.c:1275:7: warning: unused variable 'tmp_init' [-Wunused-variable]
   int tmp_init = 0;
       ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fPIC -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-1.7.0 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c c-blosc/blosc/shuffle-sse2.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/c-blosc/blosc/shuffle-sse2.o
c-blosc/blosc/shuffle-sse2.c:14:4: error: #error SSE2 is not supported by the target architecture/platform and/or this compiler.
   #error SSE2 is not supported by the target architecture/platform and/or this compiler.
    ^
c-blosc/blosc/shuffle-sse2.c:17:23: fatal error: emmintrin.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1enter preformatted text here
```

Comment: It looks like you are building a package which does not support the Pi. Second don't link to the error include it in your answer, where did you get the package? Did it claim to support the arm architecture of the Pi. Is there a precompiled binary available? what is the bigger picture - there may be alternatives available? Are you following a tutorial? If so which tutorial?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Edited to link release notes explicitly stating it should work on rpi. Also added elaboration of my install process and output.

Comment: How do you know this is supposed to work on the Pi? What version are you building?

Comment: In the "Changes from 1.3.6 to 1.4.0" release note I linked, it explicitly states that it installs on the Pi and passes all tests. I'm building from the latest code in the git repo, but see no subsequent commits or release notes suggesting that support for the Pi was intentionally removed.

Comment: it appears from the above output   "creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/blosc"   that you are ecompiling 1.3.4. as you pointed out support for the arm is only available in 1.4.0 and above.

Comment: Actually, that's not a one, that's an l ("el"); "linux-armv7l-3.4" is a standard string used to refer to the use of linux kernel version 3.4 on an ARMv7 processor.

Comment: Mike it looks like a 1 to my old eyes, but I would check with the maintainer of the code because his release is only up to 1.2.8 https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc/releases

Comment: Yes, the release numbers for c-blosc and python-blosc are out of sync.